# React, componentWillReceive lifeCycle Hook not being invoked (on passing props)

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to pass props both in App component (The root Component) and then to Header component from App itself.

I have used Life Cycle Hooks upto componentWillReceiveProps() in both App and Header Component.

componentWillMount(), render(), componentDidMount() are getting executed in both the Components in an expected order.

However, componentWillReceiveProps() is not executed at all even on passing props. This is a unExpected behaviour, since componentWillMount() was executed normally!

I shall be extremely thankful to know why is this happening ! Thank you :)

Kindly check the code sample from the below link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/r092xkpwjp

[image: ComponentWillReceiveProps]

**Please Note:** Question has been updated, and it shows both scenarios now, new props being passed (in **Header Component** which works fine now) and no new props being passed as was previously the case in the question (in **App Component** which still shows why things were working unexpectedly).

Comment: hi @Imran Rafiq Rather can you please look at this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203916/react-componentwillmount-lifecycle-hook

Comment: Hi @ParthTiwari I have mistakenly updated and worked on the same link that I have shared in the question about 1 and half year ago. As I went through all my sandboxes I have found the correct one. Here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/r092xkpwjp . If you want to know any thing about what I was trying to achieve, do let me know please. Thanks again. I am updating my Image as well as the link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you expect your components to be updated as the The props being passed to them always stay the same and no new props have been passed to these at all, but generally you should use [componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

**componentWillReceiveProps()** only gets invoked when the props passed to them are new props, different from the previous values. In the question this was not happening.

**Note:** The question has been updated now for it to work properly.

Also consider managing the state by static [getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops), i.e.:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
  // just return the state
  return {
    isLoading: false,
    money: props.money
  }
}
```

- it's executed on init + on updates.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather glad to help! It's all available in [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs), also I'd recommend to touch [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) they will be delivered in future releases, but really makes code cleaner! :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the official documentation (see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) the

```
 componentWillReceiveProps()
```

lifecycle method is deprecated and should be avoided.

The reason why it is never called is that, to help user avoid it, React developers renamed it

```
 UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()
```

You should however avoid it, since they plan to deprecate that method

Comment: This is not the reason. componentWillReceiveProps will stop working only in React 17.

Answer (score 0):

1.The main reason why the  **componentWillReceiveProps()** was not being invoked was because my props passed to **Header Component**  were not changing at all, I have been passing the same props again and again. And **componentWillReceiveProps()**  gets executed only when the props being passed are different each time.

This is what my **Header component** looked at the time of asking this question.

```
<Header
      menus={["home", "about", "services", "blog"]}
/>
```

The Header Component had only the **menus prop** as an array (at the time of asking this question) and no event was updating this **menus prop** , that's the reason why my 
 **componentWillReceiveProps()** was never invoked/called in the **Header Component**.

**Note:** To simply the things I now passed another prop to **Header Component**, and started to test my code on this *prop instead of working with the array menus prop.*

```
 <Header
    menus={["home", "about", "services", "blog"]}  
    prop={this.state.prop}
 />
```

And I am making my **state.prop** to update using an event handler:

```
 // Dynamically sending Props
  handlePropSending = () => {
   this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    prop: this.state.prop + 1
   });
  };
```

And as I am clicking on the button **'Sending Props to Header**', the new props are sent to **Header Component** and our **componentWillReceiveProps** is being called and executed succefully.

2. And same was the issue with **componentWillReceiveProps** in the **App Component**

   ReactDOM.render(, rootElement);

Since I was adding **money prop (money={9199})**, there actually is no **Parent Component** available for **money prop** to update it's value (which we could have passed to the **App Component** for it to invoke its **componentWillReceiveProps** method).

**NOTE:** *The code is updated now and there are event handlers now to make sure the props keep updated  and now the componentWillReceiveProps() method is indeed being successfully invoked.*

[componentWillReceiveProps demonstrated along with other life Cycle Hooks](https://codesandbox.io/s/r092xkpwjp)

LIKE THEY SAY :) ALL IS WELL THAT ENDS WELL :)

Comment: @Parth Tiwari Firstly my special Thanks goes to you for letting me update the question. I checked it and figured out why things where not working for me at that time (almost 1 and a half years ago). Now all seems crystal clear. :)